# How can I set drawable to a ListView in android

Tags: android, listview, imageview, drawable

I am writing a app for android 1.5.
 I want to use a complex listview to display my data.
 I want to show a ImageView of a drawable object in my List item.

I learned from a demo:

```
------> listData.put("Img", listData.put("Img", R.drawable.XXX));
listData.put("Time", "100");
listItems.add(listData);
```

It can display correctly, however, I want to change Img at runtime, The image maybe generated at run-time, so I change the code as follow, but it falls.
Can anyone help me ? many thanks!

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.item_list);
    itemListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> listItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
    for(int i = 0;i <XXX.size(); ++i) {
        HashMap<String, Object> listData = new HashMap<String, Object>();
--------->/*1)*/  listData.put("Img", new Drawable(XXX));
        /*2)*/  listData.put("Time", "100");
        /*3)*/  listItems.add(listData);
    }
    SimpleAdapter listItemAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, listItems, R.layout.listitem, new String[] { "Img", "Time"}, new int[] { R.id.listitem_img, R.id.listitem_time });
    itemListView.setAdapter(listItemAdapter);
}
```

listitem.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:paddingBottom="4dip"
    android:paddingLeft="12dip" 
    android:paddingRight="12dip">

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/listitem_img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="12dip"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listitem_time" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20dip" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one, it has helped me.

```
public class AndroidList extends ListActivity {

public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

 public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
   String[] objects) {
  super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
 }

 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  //return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

  View row = convertView;

  if(row==null){
   LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
   row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
  }

  TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.weekofday);
  label.setText(month[position]);
  ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon);

  if (month[position]=="December"){
   icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
  }
  else{
   icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icongray);
  }

  return row;
 }
}

String[] month = {
     "January", "February", "March", "April",
     "May", "June", "July", "August",
     "September", "October", "November", "December"
   };

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      //setContentView(R.layout.main);
      /*setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        R.layout.row, R.id.weekofday, DayOfWeek));*/
      setListAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(AndroidList.this, R.layout.row, month));
  }

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 //super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
 String selection = l.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
 Toast.makeText(this, selection, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

}
```

found here: http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/06/using-convertview-in-getview-to-make.html